# apt-get install pgpool2 fails on trusty

Tags: apt, postgresql

I am trying to install pgpool2 on trusty, but when using apt-get to do so it fails, like so:

`# uname -a`

```
Linux vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64 3.13.0-51-generic #84-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 15 12:08:34 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`# apt-get install pgpool2`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pgpool2 : Depends: libmemcached6 (>= 0.44) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to install pgpool2 like so:

`$ apt-get install pgpool2=3.3.2-1ubuntu1 libpgpool0=3.3.2-1ubuntu1`

For some reason the default packages for pgpool2 are broken, but when you specify these versions it installs properly.

Comment: Don't forget you can accept your4 own answer to show others this was the solution that worked

Comment: `apt-get install pgpool2` works now